# Can ts-morph work with typescript interface directly, not via files?

Tags: typescript, ts-morph

I need to extract from typescript interface into a js object. I have a function which does exactly that

```
const getKeys = (intName: string): string[] => {
  const project = new Project();
  const sourceFile = project.addSourceFileAtPath(`./${path}/${intName}.ts`);
  const node = sourceFile.getInterface(intName)!;
  const allKeys = node.getProperties().map((p) => p.getName());
  return allKeys;
};
```

But the problem is, that it requires the interface to be the default export of a seperate file. Ideally i want to provide this function not the file address, but the interface itself, something like this

```
getKeys<interfaceName>()
```

Is this possible to do with ts-morph?

Answer (score 0):

```
const source_file = project.createSourceFile('in_memory_file.ts', code)
```